# How can I combine these custom filters?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

Im trying to create a filter mechanism using this code, which works perfectly (independently):

```
    // Report Filtering
$scope.filter = {};
$scope.getCategories = function () {
    return ($rootScope.reportsData || []).map(function (report) {
        return report.type;
    }).filter(function (report, idx, arr) {
        return arr.indexOf(report) === idx;
    });
};
$scope.getPackages = function () {
    return ($rootScope.reportsData || []).map(function (report) {
        return report.package;
    }).filter(function (report, idx, arr) {
        return arr.indexOf(report) === idx;
    });
};
$scope.filterByCategory = function (reportsData) {
    return $scope.filter[reportsData.type] || noFilter($scope.filter);
};
 $scope.filterByPackage = function (reportsData) {
    return $scope.filter[reportsData.package] || noFilter($scope.filter);
};
function noFilter(filterObj) {
    for (var key in filterObj) {
        if (filterObj[key]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

and the ng-repeat is:

```
    ng-repeat="item in filtered=(reportsData | filter:filterByPackage)"
```

This works perfectly if I replace filter: with either filterByPackage or filterByCategory.

Im using this code to iterate through the keys and create checkboxes to toggle the visibility of the items:

```
<label ng-repeat="cat in getCategories()">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="filter[cat]" />{{cat}}</label>
```

However, I would like to use these both in conjunction. If i modify my inline code on the ng-repeat to:

```
ng-repeat="item in filtered=(reportsData | filter:filterByPackage | filter:filterByCategory)"
```

then clicking on checkbox makes the entire list disappear. What is the syntax to properly combine these two filters?

Comment: syntax is correct ... they won't be an OR condition if that's what you expect. Hard to help without a working demo that replicates problem. Too many unknowns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you select a category and a package you only want to display the reportData that matches with both?

The problem you are having is that you are using your "filter" object for both types of filtering and this in combination with your noFilter function that also verifies if anything is checked on the filter is causing that you need to select both a package and category exactly matching the reportData for it to be displayed (you cannot leave a filter unselected or it doesn't display any).

What you can do is initialize your filter as an object in which each criteria is a member, and utilize them as so:

```
$scope.filter = { packages: {}, categories: {}};

return $scope.filter.categories[reportsData.type] || noFilter($scope.filter.categories);

<label ng-repeat="cat in getCategories()">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="filter.categories[cat]" />{{cat}}
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks Fredy! This is my exact problem!

Comment: Fredy, I had to change reportsData.package to an array as each report can potentially belong to more than one package. How can I alter my code to accept more than one value?

Comment: I haven't tested this, but it might help you if you want to include the reports if any of the packages match the filter: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c64391a57243d71ae26480b6a9e9dd7c some of this code could be simplified a lot by using a library like jquery.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly! Unfortunately, my architects want to use pure js.